Vitest - Mock React Component only in one test
I want to mock a Component named Child in Parent. All tests should use the original Child component except one test should use a Mock. how do I achieve that?
I tried working with
vi.mock('./path/to/child.tsx', async (importActual) => ({
    ...(await importActual<typeof import('./path/to/child.tsx')>()),
    Child: vi.fn()
}));

but I cannot figure out how to mock with the actual implementation for one test and return a mock for another test.

Using spy on components works as well and is perfect for mocking a component for only one test.
I found this in the documentation:
https://vitest.dev/guide/mocking.html#cheat-sheet
Example with vi.spyOn:
import * as exports from './some-path.js'

vi.spyOn(exports, 'SomeClass').mockImplementation(() => {
    // whatever suites you from first two examples
})

and tried with mocking a component like so:
 import * as childComponent from './path/to/child.tsx'

 describe('Parent', () => {
      it('tests with mocked child', () => {
           vi.spyOn(childComponent, 'Child').mockImplementation((props: ChildProps) => {
                return (
                     <div>
                          // your component mock able to use component props as well
                     </div>
                )
      })
 })

other sources which might be helpful but didn't resolve my specific case:
Using different mocks for different tests:
https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/discussions/3589#discussioncomment-6195214
import { namedExport } from './path/to/module.js'

const mocks = vi.hoisted(() => {
    return {
        namedExport: vi.fn(),
    }
})

vi.mock('./path/to/module.js', () => {
    return {
        namedExport: mocks.namedExport,
    }
})

it('test 1', () => {
    mocks.namedExports.mockReturned(true)
    // some test
})

it('test 2', () => {
    mocks.namedExports.mockReturned(false)
    // some test
})

and this one: https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/discussions/4328
